# How do i Define MissingPermissions for a discord bot python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, discord, discord.py

```
@warn.error
async def kick_error(error, ctx):
  if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
      text = "Sorry {}, you do not have permissions to do that!".format(ctx.message.author)
      await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, text)
```

It runs but when i use the warn command it prints that MissingPermissions is not defined
How do i define it?

```
eError: name 'MissingPermissions' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

The async branch doesn't define `MissingPermissions`.  Instead, [`has_permissions`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L838) will raise `CheckFailure`.

If you wanted to write your own `has_permissions` that *does* raise a unique error, you could subclass `CheckFailure` on your own:

```
from discord.ext.commands import CheckFailure, check

class MissingPermissions(CheckFailure): pass

def has_permissions(**perms):
    def predicate(ctx):
        msg = ctx.message
        ch = msg.channel
        permissions = ch.permissions_for(msg.author)
        if all(getattr(permissions, perm, None) == value for perm, value in perms.items()):
            return True
        raise MissingPermissions() 
    return check(predicate)
```

This isn't exactly like the rewrite `has_permissions`, which includes the missing permissions in the `MissingPermissions` object, but it should be close enough to mimic the same control flow